# Proteus Ares traces do not connect

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, proteus

I am trying to connect a Vcc pin to a power source in Proteus Ares, but it does not let me do anything different from what I designed in Schematic Capture.

How can I connect the selected trace to the Vcc pin? I could try and connect the Vcc pin in the schematic first but the problem is that in the schematic version the Vcc and GND pins are hidden.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "But it does not let me do anything different from what I designed in Schematic Capture sid" then connect the chip's Vcc with your power pin in the schematic, the same way you do it with all the other pins. Also fyi you should place at least one decoupling capacitor between vcc and gnd close to your ic; ~100 nF would be a typical value.

Comment: Why not modify the schematic to match what you want to do? To force it to work anyway, you'd have to change the net of the trace to be the same as the pad you want to attach it to. I don't know how to do that in Proteus, so I'll let someone else write an answer.

Comment: As far as I know, Proteus *does not* have back annotation capability (at least in terms of attaching to different nets). The only way, as others have said, is to change the schematic to what you need.

Comment: There should be a way to show hidden pins. If I recall correctly, in Altium hidden pins were automatically connected to a net of the same name - perhaps Proteus does the same, and the hidden supply pin net is Vdd rather than Vcc - then you will have to change the hidden pin net to Vcc, or your positive supply to Vdd.  (I once got caught by this with a hidden Vss pin not connecting to GND)  After that I made sure to show all supply and ground pins.

Comment: Yes, hiddden pins can be seen in the Edit Component section. Thank you all for your time @PeterBennett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, I'm sharing my solution. So apperently if you double click the PIC Microcontroller, you can see Hidden Pins and you can type the pins you want to connect. That way PCB lets you draw the needed tracks. Here you can see, I connected VDD - VCC and VSS - GND.(VCC and GND pins are output pins of a LM317 circuit)

[image]